# Using RegEx to Extract Multiple Lines Using Alternate End of Line Characters (newline, return, end of string)

Tags: regex

I am presenting both the problem and the solution here.  I developed this after extensive research in SO, found numerous related examples, but none that matched my exact use case.

### Use Case:

- You have a source string with multiple lines, and you need to extract
  the first n lines.
- Each line could end with any of these characters: 
  newline `\n`, return `\r`, or end of string `$`

### Example Data:

The content of each line is not of interest/concern here.  The number of lines in the source string can vary, but I want to limit the number of lines to a max number.

```
Clip 08.jpg
Clip 31.jpg
Clip 31b.jpg
Clip 32.jpg
Clip 40.jpg
Clip 40b.jpg
Clip 53.jpg
Clip 54.jpg
Maui Clip 53b.jpg
```

### Answer:

`^((?:.*(?:\n|\r|$)){1,5})`

where the max number of lines, the number you want to extract, is the second number in the quantifier `{1,5}`, in this case "5".

If anyone can improve on this solution, or sees any issues with it, please post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this to be a better solution.

`(?m)(?:^.*\R?){1,20}`

https://regex101.com/r/o2D6iG/2

```
 (?m)            # Inline modifier: Multi-line mode
 (?:             # Cluster
      ^               # BOL
      .*              # optional not newlines
      \R?             # optional line terminator
 ){1,20}         # End Cluster, 1-20 times
```

If you make the line terminator optional, it takes care of EOS.
Also, when the *Multi-line* mode is in effect, it forces `\R` to match
or it will not advance.

---

If you don't have the `\R` construct, you can use the underwhelming series
of alternations for it.

`(?m)(?:^.*(?:\r?\n|\r)?){1,20}`

https://regex101.com/r/KxxeAK/1

```
 (?m)                          # Inline modifier: Multi-line mode
 (?:                           # Cluster
      ^                             # BOL
      .*                            # optional not newlines
      (?: \r? \n | \r )?            # optional line terminator
 ){1,20}                       # End Cluster, 1-20 times
```

---

And, you could likely do away with multi-line mode (it's just insurance)

`(?:.*(?:\r?\n|\r)?){1,20}`

JavaScript
https://regex101.com/r/jDTIMH/1

python
https://regex101.com/r/uqoP8Q/1

Comment: thanks for your solution.  I'm still learning RegEx, so please tell me why you think you solution is better?

Comment: Sure, you're bloating your regex with unnecessary stuff `^((?:.*(?:\n|\r|$)){1,5})` can be reduced to `^(?:.*(?:\n|\r|$)){1,5}`. And, `(?:\r?\n|\r)` is a defacto expression for all platforms, some (like windows) are untranslated, then `\r?\n` covers that. Also, there is no need for BOS anchor, since `.*` will start matching (and succeed) at BOS. And making the line break optional covers the EOS condition. I could benchmark it if needed.

Comment: Also, just a matter of trivia, given a situation like `^(?:.*$){1,20}`, this will match the empty string. Which is debatable as to whether it is really a line. That can be overcome by inserting a look ahead assertion in the beginning, like `(?=[\S\s])(?:.*(?:\r?\n|\r)?){1,20}`

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation.  You said "you're bloating your regex with unnecessary stuff ", but really, only by two characters.  .  Also, "`(?:\r?\n|\r)` is a defacto expression for all platforms". I didn't know that.  By "defacto", do you mean a common expression used to match any end of line character?  Maybe I missed it, but that did not turn up in any of my searches here. I like your last solution the best:  `(?:.*(?:\r?\n|\r)?){1,20}`

Answer (score 0):

### The following RegEx Pattern is used:

`^((?:.*(?:\n|\r|$)){1,<NumOfLinesToExtract>})`

Where `<NumOfLinesToExtract>` is the number of lines to extract from the top of the source list.  For example:
`^((?:.*(?:\n|\r|$)){1,5})`

would result in:

```
Clip 08.jpg
Clip 31.jpg
Clip 31b.jpg
Clip 32.jpg
Clip 40.jpg
```

For details, see https://regex101.com/r/Xp1jwT/2

This RegEx does the following:

- Extracts One of More Lines up  to the max number of lines set by the max parameter of the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)
- If the Source has fewer lines than the max lines, then ALL lines are returned.
- It matched a line that end in any of the following characters:

  - New Line \n
  - Return \r
  - End of String $

Comment: If you use it in .NET, each "line" will contain a trailing CR (considering the line endings are Windows style, CRLF), so, `^((?:.*(?:\n|\r|$)){1,5})` will not work quite right there.

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for the feedback.  Why doesn't the `\r` token match the .NET CR?  If not, please show how you would fix/improve the RegEx.

Comment: No, `\r` matches CR. However, the `.` also matches CR, and since `.*` is greedy, it will match up to `\n` or end of string, then will try to match `\n` - and will. So, `\r` won't be even tried. You should specify what regex flavor this should work with. It will correctly work with JS, or with PCRE with specific options.

Comment: The dot doesn't match `\r`